# Could not resolve class name for validator

Tags: php, typo3, typo3-6.2.x

i got some problems after updating my typo3 system from version 4.5 to 6.2.
If i try to open a action link, i get a error message.

```
Invalid validate annotation in Tx_UserAguGb_Controller_RiskAssessmentController->deleteAction(): 
Could not resolve class name for validator "Tx_UserAguGb_Domain_Validator_AssessmentAccess".
```

Project structure:

- user_agu_gb

  - Classes

    - Controller

      - RiskAssessmentController.php
    - Domain

      - Model

        - HazardAcessment.php
      - Repository

        - HazardAssessmentRepository.php
      - Validator

        - AssessmentAcess.php

Here are some code snippets.

RiskAssessmentController.php

```
class Tx_UserAguGb_Controller_RiskAssessmentController extends Tx_UserAguGb_Controller_ExtendedController {

/**
 * @param Tx_UserAguGb_Domain_Model_HazardAssessment|null $assessment
 * @validate $assessment Tx_UserAguGb_Domain_Validator_AssessmentAccess
 * @return void
 */
public function deleteAction(Tx_UserAguGb_Domain_Model_HazardAssessment $assessment = NULL) {
    $this->hazardAssessmentRepository->remove($assessment);
    $this->redirect('list');
}
?>
```

AssessmentAcess.php

```
<?php    
class Tx_UserAguGb_Domain_Validator_AssessmentAccess extends \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Validation\Validator\AbstractValidator {
    public function isValid($value)
    {
         someCode()...
    }
}
?>
```

List.html

```
<f:link.action action="delete"
    class="assessment-button"
    controller="RiskAssessment"
    additionalAttributes="{data-confirm:alert-delete_assessment}"
    arguments="{assessment: assessment}">
    <f:translate key="button-delete"/>
</f:link.action>
```

Comment: If i remove or replace (@ignorevalidate) the annotation, i get the same error message.

Comment: Maybe it is a namespacing problem, try to use `@validate $assessment \Tx_UserAguGb_Domain_Validator_AssessmentAccess`. Maybe even switch everything to use namespaces. Other than that, maybe you can play a bit with `class_exists()` and find the right class name? Also remember to clear the caches in the install tool after changing annotations.

Comment: Where can I clear the caches?

Comment: In the install tool, under "Important Actions".

Comment: Hmm get_declared_classes(), didn't print "Tx_UserAguGb_Domain_Validator_AssessmentAccess" and class_exists("Tx_UserAguGb_Domain_Validator_AssessmentAccess") return true